# What is required to make the Thread Sanitizer and Address Sanitizer options available in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, debugging

I don't know what I need to do to make these options stop being disabled. Any help would be appreciated:

[image]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Thread Sanitizer can be used in following preparatory condition：

1. close other option , for example 'Malloc stack'
2. need 64 bit simulator
3. after open Thread Sanitizer, need recompilation

Comment: You can also add that swift 3 is required for this

Comment: Also, make sure you have selected a simulator and not a device.

Comment: I can only select either Address Sanitizer or Thread Sanitizer, not both at the same time.

Comment: @iOSer You mean we can't run thread Sanitizer on a physical device ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz Yes, only simulator

Answer (score 2):

- It’s only supported for 64-bit macOS and 64-bit iOS and tvOS
  simulators
- watchOS is not supported
- You can’t use TSan on a device